# bash PS1 256 colors with bold

Tags: bash, terminal, colors, prompt

I want to list all colors that I can use in bash console. And after it I want to set my prompt to be bold and orange like color. I'm using this to do listing color codes for me:

```
for code in {0..255}; do echo -e "\e[38;05;${code}m $code: Test"; done
```

But the question is how to make it **bold** and keep colors?

I looked for some advice about making it bold here: http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting but I couldn't found any code that combines bold and one of 256 colors.

Comment: Add `1;` in it: `\e[1;38;05;${code}m`. Better to use `tput setaf "$code"; tput bold`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Wow I didn't know I could add another code inside sequence. I was certain whet there could be max three parts. For example: `\e[38;05;44m` or `\e[1;31m`. Does the order of codes between semicolons matter? Your answer is correct. Please write reply and I will accept it. Thx.

Comment: https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it as any of those:

```
echo -e "\e[1;38;05;${code}m $code: Test"
echo -e "\e[1m\e[38;05;${code}m $code: Test";
echo -e "\e[38;05;${code}m\e[1m $code: Test";
echo -e "\e[38;05;${code};1m $code: Test";
tput bold; tput setaf "$code" # provided the terminfo database is
                              # properly populated
```

You can run `tput bold` only once provided you don't reset the *boldness* with a `tput sgr0` or `\e[m` or `\e[0m`.

Answer (score 3):

To supplement Stephane's example, here's a quick shell function to list all 256 colors:

```
#!/bin/bash
esc=$'\033'
for row in {0..15} ; 
do
    rowtext=
    for col in {0..15}; 
    do
        color=$(( $row * 16 + $col))
        BG="${esc}[48;5;${color}m"
        rowtext=${rowtext}$BG\ 
        if [[ $color -lt 100 ]]; then rowtext=${rowtext}$BG\   ;fi 
        if [[ $color -lt 10 ]]; then rowtext=${rowtext}$BG\   ;fi 
        rowtext=${rowtext}$BG${color}
        rowtext=${rowtext}$BG\ 
    done
    echo "${rowtext}${esc}[00m "
done
```

This is a quick "port" of a zsh function I have to bash. I seems to work (in bash), or at least well enough.

The color code number is displayed in the color block. This is what you'd use in your prompt or elsewhere to set the color.

Comment: Some escape characters seems to get lost during the copy-paste.

Comment: An escape character at the beginning of `BG` got lost. You should use escape sequences instead to avoid this kind of mishap. You can't use `$BG[0]` in bash, you have to write it `${BG:0:1}` (for an array it would be `${array[0]}`).